# How to set the width of all HTML elements to the width of the widest element in the list?

Tags: html, css

Here is my structure:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">St</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">Middletext</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">This line contains a long text.</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, this code creates three lines of text, short, middle and long.

Naturally, width of each `item-title` element is equal to the length of text, so, first `item-title` element will have the smallest width, second one will have larger and the last one the largest width.

What I need to do in CSS is to set the width of all `item-title` elements to the width of the longest `item-title` element. I need this so that I can align all `item-button` elements to the same horizontal position.

Sure, I can hardcode the `width` property of all `item-title` elements, but I really need this width to be dynamic since in reality I do not have such static list of items. I use Vue to generate those list items based on the variable values that can change.

So, how can I say to HTML: "Align all buttons next to the end of the longest line of text, please"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways for achieving this, the easiest is probably a table

```css
.list
{
  display: table;
}

.list-item {
  display: table-row;
 }
 
 .item-title, .item-button {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">St</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">Middletext</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">This line contains a long text.</span>
        <button class="item-button">click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for posting so stupid question. I am stupid today. Of course, the table is the easyest solution. Thank you. I can not believe i did not think of a table.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a flexbox approach:

```css
.list {
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.list-item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.item-title {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="item-title">St</span>
    <button class="item-button">click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="item-title">Middletext</span>
    <button class="item-button">click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="item-title">This line contains a long text.</span>
    <button class="item-button">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```